# searching in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search

how can I search something in all files in a given folder in eclipse
also how can I search up, it's seems like only going down the document

sometimes I am working on single files, so there is no project defined. I know about the search in project feature

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you go to Search>Files... you'll have an advanced search dialogue where you amongst others can specify the scope to search in (all of the workspace, selected resources only etc.). Is this what you're looking for?

And also, if searching through a single file (+), you have the standard search dialogue where you can specify search direction to either forward or backward.

Comment: but still there is no where to set a folder to be searched recursively

Comment: @Maysam: yes, there is. If you select (just mark it with your mouse) e.g. a folder (or a package or whatever), and then go to Search>Files and select the scope "Selected resources", it will only search the folder you have selected.

Comment: @Nailuj this does not work when you select "Java Resources". You have to select a "src" or other **directory**.

Answer (score 8):

- Search **forward in file**: Edit -> Incremental Find Next
- Search **backward in file**: Edit -> Incremental Find Previous
- Search **in multiple files**: Search -> File -> Containing Text.
- Search **files in a specific subdirectory**: Select the sub-directory -> Search -> File -> Scope: Selected resources.

I reccomend that you learn the short-cuts for these tasks. (Key-combination is found right beside the menu-item.)

Comment: but still there is no where to set a folder to be searched recursively

Answer (score 4):

When you are searching "Java Resources" with "File Search" with "Selected resources" checkbox checked - you will not get any results.

To search recursively a chosen folder for any files:

1. Select folder (it has to be folder)

[image]

2. Select FileSearch with "Selected resources" checked.

[image]

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Use the Remote Search Feature. Here you can browse for local folders. Some stupid name...

Answer (score 2):

If default eclipse search is not sufficient for your needs, [eclipse instasearch plugin](https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch) is a very useful plugin for search needs inside eclipse.

It is based on lucene. This is also available in eclipse marketplace.
It has extensive feature set.

- Instantly shows search results
- Shows a preview using relevant lines
- Periodically updates the index
- Matches partial words (e.g. case in CamelCase)
- Opens and highlights matches in files
- Searches JAR source attachments
- Supports filtering by extension/project/working set

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for anything without telling Eclipse what it is, use ctrl+shift+L  (QuickEclipseSearch). This is the quickest way.
You can also use 'file search' (press ctrl+H) and navigate into file search using left and right arrrows on the top right corner of your windows. Or type 'file search' in the 'Quick Access' window. 
If you are looking for a specific method, package, field,type or constructor use JAVA search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want search in a particular file then just press ctr+F and type whatever you want to search in that current file.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the answers above but couldn't figure out the solution working for me. Finally gave a thought process keeping in mind all the solutions provided here and voila it worked for what I'm looking here. Thanks stackoverflow, this site is awesome.

Solution I worked out:
Goto Navigator window in eclipse, select the folder where you want to perform the search operation, now click Alt a & f (shortcut) which opens the file search window. Now select the option "Selected resources" in 'scope' section and hit 'Search' button.

Answer (score 0):

In MAC I use, control+H (^H), it opens a window, where you can search for any text within all the files.